# Cómo puedo eliminar un objeto dinámicamente en C# WINFORMS?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando objetos de forma dinámica continuamente, pero también necesito eliminar estos objetos en algún momento, por ahora estoy utilizando `object.Visible = false;`, pero sigue estando ahí... cómo lo puedo eliminar?

Comment: para borrar un objeto debes poner: objeto.Dispose()

Answer (score 1):

Según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-to-or-remove-from-a-collection-of-controls-at-run-time?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#to-remove-controls-from-a-collection-programmatically), debes:

1. Quitar los event handlers asociados al control.
2. Quitar el control de [`Controls`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls).
3. Ejecutar la función [`Dispose`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.dispose).

El código sería algo así:

```
this.Controls.Remove(control);
control.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregue a todos los controles dinámicos algunos Tag, por ejemplo "dynamic". Luego deséchelos de esta manera:
`foreach (Label label in Controls.OfType<Label>()){ if (label.Tag != null && label.Tag.ToString() == "dynamic") label.Dispose();     }`